# JMeter's RegEx Post Processor returns null

Tags: jmeter

The following is a contrived demo that reproduces the issue I was having with a larger, real Test Plan.  I have 3 screen captures to demonstrate how the RegEx PostProcessor never matches during execution.

[**EDIT**] *Note that in my screenshots that the Response Field to Check is shown as "Response Message".  I had already tested Body and got "null" as explained.  Screencaps would have been better had they shown Body selected with null result, but this should still make sense*)

**1)** Here's the HTML of the Sampler's Response in the View Tree:
[FIGURE 1](http://www.mobypicture.com/user/stevenerat/view/13018880/sizes/full).

Notice I'm using the Regex [Pp]age\s\d{1} to successfully find the desired text "Page 1" in the HTML in the first sampler response.

**2)** Here's the RegEx PostProcessor on the first Sampler:
[FIGURE 2](http://www.mobypicture.com/user/stevenerat/view/13018875/sizes/full).

Notice it uses the same Regex as in previous screen capture, and default text is "notfound", and the resulting variable is "TempVar".

- **a)** Screen capture shows "Main Sample" & "Response Message" selected.  This returns default text.
  **b)** Not shown - I tried "Main Sample" & "Body", but that returns null.

**3)** Here's the second sampler's Path where the result of the first sampler regex is fed into a URL parameter as `?MyVar=${TempVar}`
[FIGURE 3](http://www.mobypicture.com/user/stevenerat/view/13018877/sizes/full).

Now go back to look again at [FIGURE 1](http://www.mobypicture.com/user/stevenerat/view/13018880/sizes/full) where you will see that during execution the dynamic URL on the second sampler becomes "MyVar=notfound" when using "Response Message" (it becomes "MyVar=null" if using "Body" instead).

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.  I've tried every combination in the RegEx Extractor screen, but I have never been able to get it return the matching text from the expression.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the regex you're using to:

```
<h3>This\sis\s([^<]*)<\\/h3>
```

Whilst the regex you're using does work (it will match on Page 1) because it is not using the () notation to return a value to the variable, you're ending up with null. The braces are required to denote what is sent back.

Check out [this page](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html), it gives more detail on how JMeter works with regexs.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  I was not aware of the use of parentheses in that manner.  I expected that because the base regex worked without parens in the FIND on the Response that it would be suitable for use in the Regex field of the Regex Extractor.